# Importing a C DLL into Delphi issues with includes

Tags: c, delphi, dllimport

I am investigating the use of the libpostal library from GitHub.  I am trying to use it with Delphi Toyoko and I have used Dr Bob's headconv utility to generate the following but if I try and use it it complains about missing.h files.   I can find these via Embarcadero but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  Any help would be really appreciated.

I have done some searching but cannot find an answer.

```
unit LIBPOSTAL;
 {*************************************************************************}
{                                                                          }
{    This C DLL header file first (automatic) conversion generated by:     }
{    HeadConv 4.0 (c) 2000 by Bob Swart (aka Dr.Bob - www.drbob42.com)     }
{      Final Delphi-Jedi (Darth) command-line units edition                }
{                                                                          }
{    Generated Date: 04/04/2019                                            }
{    Generated Time: 15:01:11                                              }
{                                                                          }
{**************************************************************************}

interface
uses
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  Windows;
{$ELSE}
  Wintypes, WinProcs;
{$ENDIF}


{=> c:\libpostal\src\LIBPOSTAL.H <=}

{$IFNDEF LIBPOSTAL_H}
{$DEFINE LIBPOSTAL_H}

{$IFDEF __cplusplus}
{$ENDIF}

{$INCLUDE <stdio.h>}
{$INCLUDE <stdlib.h>}
{$INCLUDE <stdint.h>}
{$INCLUDE <stdbool.h>}

{$IFDEF _WIN32}
{$IFDEF LIBPOSTAL_EXPORTS}
const
  LIBPOSTAL_EXPORT = __declspec(dllexport);
{$ELSE}
const
  LIBPOSTAL_EXPORT = __declspec(dllimport);
{$ENDIF}
{$ELSE __GNUC__ >= 4}
const
  LIBPOSTAL_EXPORT = __attribute__ ((visibility('default')));
{$ELSE}
{$DEFINE LIBPOSTAL_EXPORT}
{$ENDIF}

const
  LIBPOSTAL_MAX_LANGUAGE_LEN = 4;

const
  s = so we can duplicate the values exactly in Python;
```

I would expect the librarys to load so that I can - use the libpostal.dll - if this will never work this way please let me know.

Comment: These are all standard libraries on the C side. Have you tried commenting them out, the includes?

Comment: FWIW, I'd advise you to read my article on such conversions: [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html). It explains a lot of what is wrong with that and how you can proprely convert. Dr.Bob's  HeadConv is nice, but in my (vast) experience, only a manual (or assisted manual) conversion can do the trick. Take a look at my [Conversion Pack](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html) conversion assistant package for the IDE too. I use it myself when converting headers.

Comment: FWIW, you can remove the {$INCLUDE <...>} entries, and the {$IFNDEF ..._H} stuff too. That is needed in C, which uses text includes, but a Delphi unit doesn't need it. These includes are C anyway, so Delphi can't use them. Also the `__declspec` and `__attribute__` stuff is totally irrelevant for Delphi. You don't need it. Your `const
  s = so we can duplicate the values exactly in Python;` doesn't make any syntactic sense, unless you meant it to be a string: `const
  s = 'so we can duplicate the values exactly in Python';`

Comment: You'll need to translate that manually. It looks relatively simple, at least compared to some you might find

Comment: FWIW, to test my Convertpack, I downloaded and translated libpostal.h to libpostal.pas. The result can be found [on my webpage](http://www.rvelthuis.de/zips/libpostal.pas). Note that this was a one-off test. I did not check if it works, or if it is correct (but I guess so, as most of it was done by ConvertPack). If you need help, read my article. FWIW, ConvertPack still needs some minor corrections. What it converts is correct, but it sometimes refuses to convert valid constructs. <g>

Comment: FWIW, I'll leave it there for a while, but if you want it, get it now. It may disappear on the next cleanup of my website.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis that was very helpful :-)  I test that unit and it seems to allow the DLL to load!   My next issue is trying to understand how to code it to use it :-(

Comment: @Phil: The readme on github is pretty extensive.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  I have read the read me and can see the C examples working - but have not managed to translate one into Delphi yet to work.  It's my lack of understanding C syntax I think :-(  Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: The best thing for you to do is bet a beginner book on C and learn enough C to read and translate simple code samples. If you know Delphi you can learn basic C in no time. Doing this will have long term benefits for you.

Comment: @david heffernan thanks good idea :)

Comment: I Have managed to get the library to work.  I found a reply that @DavidHeffernan had written about {POINTERMATH} and using that - and looking at the C source code I can get the library to load now and work :-)  Many thanks!